# I am trying to delete a string from list then write it back to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

The assignment isPhase 1 - Management mode
When the user selects management mode, they should be allowed to do the following:

1. Add a new product to the list (must also add how many of the item 
   and its cost)
2. Remove a product from the list
3. Change the quantity of an item

   ```
   def mang (grocerystock):

   mangchoice=int(input("What would you like to do? \n 1):Add a new product to the list? \n 2): Remove a product from the list?  \n 3: Change the quantity of an item  \n 4): Change the price of an item  \n  5): View items and their quantity and price"))

   if mangchoice == 1:
       infile=open("grocery_stock.txt", 'a')
       name=input("Please enter the new product's name would you like to add:")
       quant=int(input("Please enter the new product's quantity"))
       price=float(input("Please enter the new product's price"))
       grocerystock[0]=name
       grocerystock[1]=quant
       grocerystock[2]=price
       gS=str(grocerystock)
       gs=gS.strip("[',']")
       infile.write(gs + '\n')
   if mangchoice == 2:
       namedelete=input("what item would you like to remove")
       a=open("grocery_stock.txt", 'r')
       data_list= a.readlines()
       a.close()
       print (data_list)
       del data_list[namedelete]
       b= open ("grocery_stock.txt", 'w')
       b.writelines(data_list)
       b.close()
   def intro():
   choice=(int(input("Would you like to go to Managerial mode or Shop mode?(press 1 for Managerial and 2 for shop mode, to quit press 3)")))


   if choice == 1:
       print ('lets go')
       mang(grocerystock)
   elif choice == 0 :
       print ('loser')

   grocerystock= ["","",""]

   intro()
   ```

This is all the code i have written so far any ideas? The code that i am trying to delete is under if mangchoice == 2:

Comment: Do not cross-post questions. You asked the same question on Programmers. If the question is deemed acceptable, it will be migrated to the proper site by a moderator.

Comment: You will want to look into using the [``with`` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for opening files. It deals with closing and exceptions for you, and reads well.

Comment: Sorry @MikeL. I did not know, first time posting, I assumed that I was supposed to do that judging by the responses on the previous post. Once again sorry will not happen again.

Comment: @bradb - np, just wanted to make you aware. The people suggesting you post your question here should have mentioned the migration process.

Comment: Do *you* have any ideas? What do you need help with? "What have you tried"?

Comment: @alexis I actually decided to completely change it up and go at it using the dictionary{} I believe this will help me better when trying to take out certain values and replacing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python3, `input` returns a string. It looks like you need to convert it to an `int`:

```
namedelete = int(input("what item would you like to remove"))
```